# array_diff() in PHP is giving unexpected information

Tags: php, arrays

This is the contents of my file `spectrum_info.txt`:

```
raid,spectrum/raid_info.txt
rbid,spectrum/rbid_info.txt
rcid,spectrum/rcid_info.txt
rdid,spectrum/rdid_info.txt
reid,spectrum/reid_info.txt
```

When I load this file data using below code

```
$s_types=file('spectrum/spectrum_info.txt');
$i=0;
foreach($s_types as $s_type)
{
    $s_arrfields = explode(',', $s_type);
    $s_names[] = $s_arrfields[0];
    $sf_names[] = $s_arrfields[1];
}
```

I put `file_names` information from the above file into `$sf_names` array.
Manually I created one other array having same data:

```
$f_temp=array("spectrum/raid_info.txt",
                                          "spectrum/rbid_info.txt",
                                          "spectrum/rcid_info.txt",
                                          "spectrum/rdid_info.txt",
                                          "spectrum/reid_info.txt",
                                          "spectrum/rfid_info.txt",
                                          "spectrum/rgid_info.txt",
                                          "spectrum/rhid_info.txt");
                            print_r($f_temp);
                            echo"<br/>";
                            print_r($sf_names);
                            echo"<br/>";
                            $result=array_diff($f_temp,$sf_names);
                            print_r($result);
```

Both arrays are having same data. Still `array_diff()` shows all array elements as being different.

I'm trying this because, when i used `$sf_names` file information to read data from that particular file I get the below error.

> Warning: file(spectrum/raid_info.txt ): failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Please help me regarding `array_diff()` as how to change data loaded from a file equal to manually created array. It can be useful in solving the above error. Thanks.

Comment: you need to fix file() first

Comment: RTFM: [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) `Return values: ... Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, with the newline still attached` so array_diff is working perfectly, but you're comparing `"foo" == "foo\n"`

Comment: @MarcB Looks to me like the file could not even be opened.

Comment: I should have read file() first :P Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

The values returned by `file()`, by default, contain the newline character at the end of each line. The `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag can be used to drop the newline from each value.

```
$s_types = file('spectrum/spectrum_info.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

For full details, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php